# Monitoring directory for changes - potential high memory

Tags: memory, node.js, filesystems, directory

I'm currently using a script in nodeJS to monitor a directory (and it's sub directories), and do some function once a file has been placed there. In reality, this would be an FTP, where users upload files, it is processed, then deleted.

Obviously, i'm already seeing some high amount in CPU usage with the script, as it traverses over the directories, waiting for files to be visible. But what worries me is that the longer the script runs, the higher the memory usage (it just keeps rising exponentially). Are there some lightweight ways to monitor a directory for changes?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm currently using [watch-tree](https://github.com/tafa/node-watch-tree) which is great, but still has the increasing-memory issue.

Comment: What your identifying is a memory leak in 3rd party code. Try using `supervisor` it's less likely to have a memory leak. (It's made by Isaacs!!)

Comment: Sounds like a great alternative! How can I monitor a directory (and sub-directories) when files are added? Node-supervisor seems to only watch a file for changes (server.js for instance)

Comment: it also watches any sub directories for all `.js` files. If you try `supervisor --help` it should have a `-js` option for more detailed control.

Comment: Thanks @Raynos, i've started configuring it, and am using the follow command - supervisor -w Sites/data -e txt Sites/server.js - which, according to the docs with monitor the Sites/data folder for txt files. My question is, how do I access those changes? I want to be able to pass in the files that it picks up that have changed to process in my server.js...

Comment: by default supervisor restarts your server on file change. This is hot reloading. There is no progamatic API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a wrapper around FAM or inotify. Maybe something like [node-inotify-plusplus](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-inotify-plusplus/) would work for you.

Comment: Thanks @rjp, I've been since looking into something like that. My main issue with any solution is the level of memory that'll be taken up by the monitoring process, as this system needs to be online for 8 hours at a time. Is inotify a good way to go? From what i've researched, it's apart of the OS, so would be highly memory-efficient...

Comment: FreeBSD/OS X users will need to use a kqueue solution as inotify/epoll does not exist on those platforms.

Comment: Can you use node-inotify-plusplus to print the names of files as the files in the directory are modified?

Comment: Also, are any working example programs (using node-inotify) available? I think we need some concrete examples of a solution to this problem (and the documentation for node-inotify is rather confusing, so some examples would be helpful here.)

Comment: @rjp can u tell me how does it differ from [fs.watch](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) in official node api?

Comment: @AvinashR node-inotify-plusplus seems to be a more polished approach since fs.watch is still marked as unstable even in the latest Node docs. Only helps if you're on Linux, mind...