# Get notification in node.js when file is added to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, watch

I'm writing some node.js code in which I would like to trigger action when a file is loaded to a directory, or when that file is updated there --I'm expecting that the same file name will be replaced in the directory repeatedly.

So, when the node child process finishes saving a file to the watched directory, I would like to trigger subsequent processes that use that file:

This thread seemed related, but not quite explicit enough about how to know when the file is updated or replaced: [Watch a folder for changes using node.js, and print file paths when they are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695046/watch-a-folder-for-changes-using-node-js-and-print-file-paths-when-they-are-cha)

Implicitly, I also need to verify that the updating process to the file in the watched directory is complete before the next events would be triggered.

Thanks as always for your advice!

Comment: If you are streaming data into a file in a separate process than what is watching, there is no way to really know when it is "done" unless you know the size of the file that it should be at when it is "complete"

Comment: You can periodically check the file-size at say intervals of 100ms, and so long as the file-size is greater than it was on last check, you can assume the writing is incomplete.

Comment: @levi but assuming that on a check where size doesn't increase, that it is done is an assumption that may not be true (see: network latency, disk latency, task switching, etc).

Comment: @Chad valid point. I suppose if you really wanted to, the writing process could prepend the file contents with a string "IS_WRITING", and remove it once done. And the watching process could periodically read the first few bytes of the file, and check for the absence of the string.

Comment: @levi Yeah, OP can you give us a little more information about what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe we can suggest a more robust solution?

Comment: Thx for your response.  I have a process in node which spawns a child python script against an API.  The result is ultimately a json file in a particular directory.  Being new to this stuff, I thought maybe file creation events had some data to tell you when they were completely done saving the file, so that I could code a call back around receiving that "completely done" value.  But based on what you're saying about checking file size repeatedly, I gather that's not things work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the thread you linked it pretty explicit, isn't it? You can either use the standard methods `fs.watch` and `fs.watchFile`, or a nice little wrapper such as https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar. i.e:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('dir/', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});

watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been added');})
```

Comment: This is giving an 'add' event for every file in the folder every time just one file is added. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @JoeBeuckman that's definitely not intended behaviour. I am pretty sure the problem is on your side but you can always open an issue on github.

Comment: I sent him a test that fails in a strange way but should be testing this: https://github.com/jbeuckm/chokidar/commit/3ba1bb85a9291c242cf256c9bce85a6065cb1578

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notify` as well.

```
var Notify = require('fs.notify');

var files = [
  '/path/to/file',
  '/file/i/want/to/watch'
];

var notifications = new Notify(files);
notifications.on('change', function (file, event, path) {
  console.log('caught a ' + event + ' event on ' + path);
});

// if you want to add more files you can use the
notifications.add([path, morepaths]);

// kill everything
notifications.close();
```

But `chokidar` is better.