# Recursive Node.js fs.watch on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_caveats states that `fs.watch(filename[, options][, listener])`'s recursive option is only available to OS X and Windows.

So, how could it be implemented on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Use [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)
Found answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705878/2119164)