# How to work with SetInterval and Promises

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a function:

```
function update_log_file(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        setInterval(function(){
            let logFile = '\\\\network\\sharedfolder\\GG\\' + moment(Date.now()).format('YYMMDD') + 'data_log.txt';

                let log_with_batch = {
                    log: logFile,
                    batch: 'new'
                }

                resolve(log_with_batch);

        }, 2000);


    });
}
```

and the invoker:

```
    update_log_file().then(function(log_with_batch){
       console.log(log_with_batch);
       tail = new Tail(log_with_batch.log);
       tail.on('line', function(data){
        console.log(data)
       });

       tail.error('error', function(error){
        console.log(error)
       });
    });
```

How am I able to see the object "log_with_batch" every 2 secs using promises and setInterval?

Please feel free to correct my functions.
Thank you!

Comment: Why you want to use a promise for this? whith setInterval it will work. Promises resolves just one time.

Comment: @jonhid: Because I have a tail [node-tail](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail) (Apology for not including in the code) If I use node-tail inside the setInterval the listener will multiply over time.

Comment: "*How to work with promises and `setInterval`*" - you don't. Promises resolve only once, an interval fires multiple times. And yes, your `node-tail` lib already fires multiple `line` events, there is absolutely no need to use `setInterval` here? Don't use it, don't use promise, just call `new Tail` and install your event listeners.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for clarification. I appreciated it. I'm thinking if I just call `new Tail` I may not be able to change the filename (pathTofilename) according to the system date.

Comment: Oh that's what you're trying to do! I think for that you'll want to [watch the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13695046/1048572) for new files appearing, or just check the date on every `line` event, and then open another `new Tail` on the new file.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks! I'll definitely try that. I'll get back to you once it's done

Comment: @Bergi: It works now! :D

Comment: @xtranghero You might want to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Bergi: Did an overnight testing, but the tailing stopped. I have to change the code first. 
Here's the code: 
`let pathToLog = '\\\\network\\shared\\p\\a\\t\\h\\moment(Date.now()).format('YYMMDD') + '_data_log.txt';

if(pathToLog){
tail = new Tail(pathToLog);
}

fs.watch(pathToLog, (eventType, filename) => {
   if('${eventType}' == 'rename'){
      tail = new Tail(pathToLog);
      console.log(tail);
   }
});

tail.on('line', function(data){
   console.log(data);
});

tail.on('error', function(error){
   console.log(error);
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Check this, In `update_log_file` you don't need the promise. Promise resolves only once.

```
function tailExec() {
    let logFile = '\\\\network\\sharedfolder\\GG\\' + moment(Date.now()).format('YYMMDD') + 'data_log.txt';
    tail = new Tail(logFile );
    tail.on('line', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
    tail.error('error', function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

setInterval(tailExec, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the function will multiply the tail over time...