# How to run a Node.js script when a new file is downloaded to a specific directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, dom-events

I want to make a sorting system on my computer, that sorts all the files from the Downloads directory into different groups. For this, I first need to know how to run a Node.js script every time when a new file is added to Downloads. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695046/watch-a-folder-for-changes-using-node-js-and-print-file-paths-when-they-are-cha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watch a folder for changes using node.js, and print file paths when they are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695046/watch-a-folder-for-changes-using-node-js-and-print-file-paths-when-they-are-cha)