# watch folder is added using node

Tags: chokidar

i rewrote a example found here [Watch a folder for changes using node.js, and print file paths when they are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695046/watch-a-folder-for-changes-using-node-js-and-print-file-paths-when-they-are-cha)
using [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

i want know when a folder is added to my folder (only interested in folders not files).

i rewrote the example to:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('\.\');

watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been added');})
  .on('change', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');})
  .on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');})
  .on('error', function(error) {console.error('Error happened', error);})
```

whith no effect. when i add a new folder i get no message.

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Make sure the path to the folder you are watching is correct. Put an absolute path to check out.

Comment: Where do you expect a path like `\.\ ` to point to?

Comment: using a absolute path adds all already existing folders but also files. so yes it has effect

Comment: using absolute path it adds all already existing folders, files and all from subfolders.