Monitor an images folder to get a live local html/javascript gallery
I need to get a live image gallery based on a permanently monitored folder. It will run on my local computer. Here is how it should work:

If an image file appears, it is automatically added to the gallery
If an image file disappear, it is automatically removed from the gallery
If an image file is modified, the image has to be refreshed in the gallery
Do not use of an automatique page refresh: Each image have to be clicked to be enlarged in the same full window
And, as said  above, each image have to be clickable to be zoomed full size from the origin, in the same window (like here for sample: https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/zoom-from-origin/)

Based on some samples founded in Stackoverflow, I've done that. But it doesn't refresh img. And if I well understand the code, it will not remove an image if the file disappear. What do you think? (As you can see I'm not very used with new technologies... I'm an old html/css webmaster)
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script>

function refresh(node)
{
   var times = 1000; // gap in Milli Seconds;

   (function startRefresh()
   {
      var address;
      if(node.src.indexOf('?')>-1)
       address = node.src.split('?')[0];
      else 
       address = node.src;
      node.src = address+"?time="+new Date().getTime();

      setTimeout(startRefresh,times);
   })();

}

window.onload = function()
{
  var node = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
  refresh(node);
  // you can refresh as many images you want just repeat above steps
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="ajax-inserted-content">
    <section class="section gallery grid layout-4-col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id='gallery-items'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
function doPortItem(n) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './imgportfolio/test-' + n + '.jpg';
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let div = `<div class="col-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="gallery-item">
       <div class="gallery-img">
         <img class="img" data-lazy-image data-src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzIDIiPjwvc3ZnPg==" src="${img.src}" alt="Demo img"> 
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>`;
        document.querySelector('#gallery-items').innerHTML += div;
        doPortItem(++n)
    })
}
doPortItem(1)
</script>

</body>
</html>


Unfortunately this is not something you can do client side only.   What you describe could be done using some server side process, and then maybe use something like Websocket protocol.   But be warned, It's not a trivial process..

As @Keith said you will need to do it in the server side, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44588417/4191561

Ok. But if obtain all of my goal are not possible, what is possible in javascript client side only? Based on what I've already done (or with a better approach) ?
In fact, I can't run a PHP server. It has to work in local computer, monitoring a folder in the same local computer.

In short: you can't read a directory completely client-based because this would be a security nightmare: you could easily crawl a user's file system.
Workaround - Client-based-only: requiring a predictable naming scheme
If you really can't run a local server supporting server side scripts like php your only chance is probably to deploy a consistent numeric image file-name scheme and hide non-existent images in the gallery view like img-1 to img-100:


let dir = 'https://picsum.photos/id';
let suffix = '/100/100';
let start = -3;
let end = 3;

// init
loadImages(dir);

// reload
let interval = 60 * 1000;
setInterval(loadImages, interval);


function loadImages(dir) {
  let html = '';

  //reset content
  imageGrid.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    let src = `${dir}/${i}${suffix}`;
    html +=
      `<a href="${dir}/${i}${suffix}" data-lg-size="100-100">
         <img onerror="this.parentNode.classList.add('broken-image')" src="${src}">
      </a>`;
  }
  imageGrid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

}
.imageGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.broken-image {
  display: none;
}
   

<h3>3 images are hidden as they don't exist</h3>
<div id="imageGrid" class="imageGrid"></div>



This is rather a hack and by no means great.
In fact we're assuming we have 6 images named by a predictable index suffix.
If an image can't be loaded it is hidden via onerror callback function.
If you have control of the file naming conventions – this is probably the best you can get from 100% client-side approach.
Updating file list
The directory-list updates would rely on a recurring method call like setInterval().  You can't get a proper live-update and should probably avoid too many updates – for instance an update each minute (or every 5 minutes) is more reasonable than updating every second.
Re-initializing gallery scripts
When updating the gallery you would usually need to initialize the gallery script (binding lightbox events etc.)
Local server
I highly recommend to install a local server providing e.g php functionality. For instance via an application like xampp, mampp etc.
In this case you could write a php script responding to a JS fetch() call like so:
JavaScript
We're sending a POST request via fetch() to a php script which return a file list for the specified directory including only certain file types.
// directory to search for image files
let dir = 'img';

// allowed file extensions
let extensions = ['webp', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif'];

// php script url for directory listing
let phpScan = 'filelist.php';

// update interval: ever minute = 60000ms
let interval = 60 * 1000;

let fileList;

// init async call
(async () => {

    //init
    fileList = await getFilelist(dir, phpScan, extensions);
    updateGallery(fileList);

    setInterval(async () => {
        fileList = await getFilelist(dir, phpScan, extensions);
        updateGallery(fileList)
    }, interval)

})();


// dummy update function
function updateGallery(fileList) {
    console.log(fileList);
}

/**
 * retrieve file directory info 
 * via php script
 */
async function getFilelist(dir, phpScan, extensions) {
    let list = await (await fetch(
        phpScan,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                dir: dir,
                extensions: extensions
            })
        })).json();
    return list;
}

If you're using a local server you may also use this approach as described by fmacdee: "How to list files inside folder using fetch?".
This approach takes for granted your local server has directory listing enabled. In other words: the server will automatically generate a HTML table view you can "parse" via fetch result. Here is a modified version:

async function getDirectory(dir, extensions) {
    let response = await fetch(dir);
    let html = await response.text();
    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    console.log(doc);

    let files = [...doc.querySelectorAll("a")].map(a => {
        // filter allowed extenstion
        let ext = a.href.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
        if (extensions.includes(ext)) {
            let filename = a.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
            let mod = a.parentNode.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim()
            return { filename: filename, href: a.href, mod: mod }
        }
        return
    }
    ).filter(Boolean)

    return files;
}

All in all: I highly recommend to take the time to install a local server.
We certainly won't see any new JS features that allow client-side directory listing, as this would have huge security implications.

Thanks for this so detailed response :D I've tried your client-based-only workaround: it works. But because I need to get new pictures in real time, I'm force to set interval to 1 second. And so, I can't add a click and zoom script on each image because it will be refreshed, and so disappear, each second. I'll try to find if it's possible to install a local server. Thanks :)
